# In cell division, are daughter cells "newer" than the parent cell?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-division

I learned that cells go through cell division to generate new cells to replace dead or damaged cells.

Are the daughter cells "newer" than the parent cells? For example, the parent cell has an "age" of 9 days and the daughter cells will have an "age" of 2 days.  Because if they are not "newer" than the parent cells and all have an "age" of 9 days, they will all still die  together at the same time in the end.

For a real world example, skin cells only live a few weeks. But not all skin cells on our body die after a few weeks. So the only logical way I can think of to get around this is that daughter cells are "newer" or "younger" than parent cells. Or perhaps my notion about the "age" of cells is wrong.

And if the daughter cells are "newer", why is that possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Biology@SE! Have you read about [telomeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomere)? In general, you have to define "cell age" more precise, i think

Comment: I think you need to read about cell ageing and sort out what you mean by new and how the two do or do not relate and then come back with a properly defined question.

Comment: There may be an interesting question here. Cell division can be asymmetric (asymmetric partitioning of the biomolecules and orgaqnelles) and the "age" of the two cells can be different. This is at least known in yeast. Are you asking about something similar?